# C echo user input

Tags: c

So I am a very beginner to C programming (I have used Ruby, Python and Haskell before) and I am having trouble getting the most simple thing to work in C (probably because of all the manual memory stuff). Anyway, what I am trying to do is (using simple constructs) make a script that just echoes what the user inputs to the console.

e.g. user inputs hi, console prints hi.

This is what I came up with.

Also, I haven't really mastered pointers, so none of that.

```
// echo C script

int echo();

int main() {

    echo();
    return 0;

}

int echo() {
    char input[500];

    while (1) {
        if (scanf("%[^\n]", input) > 0) {
            printf("%s\n", input);
        }
        input[0] = 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I realize that there is a bunch of bad practices here, like setting a giant string array, but that is just for simplifying it.

Anyway, my problem is that it repeats the first input then the input freezes. As far as I can tell, it freezes during the while loop (1 is never returned).

Any help would be appreciated.

Oh, and using TCC as the compiler.

Comment: As is, there's no way to escape the while loop, so you'll never reach the return. Not sure why the input is freezing though

Comment: it isnt really supposed to leave the while loop. the problem is that I cannot input anything after the first loop, when I should be able to

Comment: @Jori resetting the input variable?

Comment: Yes, but that should be `input[0] = '\0';`

Comment: @Jori, no difference, I believe

Comment: It's getting stuck on your `scanf` format string. After it scans for "anything but a carriage return" it then encounters a carriage return and can't get past that because you have no scan for it. At that point, `scanf` continues to return 0.

Comment: @abelenky, even if he changed compilers his code, as is, would still have the same problem.

Comment: I think he means Tiny C Compiler (TCC) for the Windows platform, rather than Turbo-C.

Comment: @Jori:  I was unaware of Tiny C.  Thanks. (deleting earlier comments).

Comment: @abelenky - yeah you are indeed correct on that. I did enjoy your "first girlfriend" metaphor. :)

Comment: @mbratch is right, if you [add a getchar()](http://ideone.com/Sz3prq) it works as expected

Comment: Yes, when saying TCC I meant Tiny C Compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine that you have such a large string allocated, as long as it's possible for users to input a string of that length. What I would use for input is `fgets` (read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) for more information).  Proper usage in your situation, given that you still would like to use the string of size 500, would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int echo(){
    char input[500];
    while(fgets(input, 500, STDIN)){  //read from STDIN (aka command-line)
        printf("%s\n", input);  //print out what user typed in
        memset(input, 0, strlen(input));  //reset string to all 0's
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Note that changing the value of 500 to whatever smaller number (I would normally go with some power of 2 by convention, like 512, but it doesn't really matter) will limit the length of the user's input to that number. Also note that I didn't test my code but it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an array for echo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) putchar(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this only prints one character at a time to stdin, right?

Comment: Yes, `getchar` read one character (buffered until RETURN is hit) and `putchar` prints one character

Comment: Ah, didn't think of the buffering aspect, I thought it would just print single characters as you typed them.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%[^\n]", input`

Should be:

`scanf("%s",input)`

Then after your if you should do:

`memset(input,0,500);`

Comment: why do you need to set all line to `0`? Whats problem with setting just first character?

Comment: There is no real reason, aside from erasing all data in the array. Simply doing what you said would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of accomplishing this task however the easiest would be to read from stdin one byte at a time and output that byte to stdout as you process each byte.

**Snippet:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
  // Iterates until EOF is sent.
  for ( int byte = getchar(); byte != EOF; byte = getchar() ) {
    // Outputs to stdout the byte.
    putchar( byte );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Remark:**

- You must store the byte that you are reading through stdin in an integer. This is because you are not guaranteed that char is signed or unsigned, there are in fact 3 char types in C (char, signed char and unsigned char). Include the limits library to determine whether a char is signed or not in your environment.
- You must compile using the C99 standards, otherwise move the declaration of byte outside of the for loop.